# Is there any reference to design a 4*4 bit ram only using transistors

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, ram, pspice, sram

I'm currently doing a project and would like some help. I need to create a 4-bit 4-word RAM using PSPICE. (I'm both new to the PSPICE program and new to the topic of RAM)

I currently have successfully created a 6t memory cell with the following values:
[image: 6T Memory Cell PSPICE]

Its working well, but due to lack of resources on this topic, I'm not sure how I can turn it into something that looks like this:

[image: RAM reference]

I was also given a reference image on how a sense amplifier looks:
[image: sense amplifier reference]

My question is, is there any reference of a 4*4 bit RAM only using transistors that I could look at as a reference? What type of decoder is normally used for this type of RAM and does each cell need a sense amplifier? I'd appreciate any help with the topic, even if it's just a reference picture.

References for image 2 and 3: Sedra/Smith Microelectronic Circuits 6th ed.

Comment: The only thing immediately to mind is the 7481 and 7484. They are 4x4. But BJT. By the time CMOS arrived (roughly a decade later, maybe a little more) memory sizes had greatly expanded and no one was nearly so interested in a 4x4. So I don't have a useful suggestion for an example to look at.

Comment: @jonk thanks for the advice, would you know which type of decoder can be used here?

Comment: ? something like this ? https://moodle.insa-toulouse.fr/file.php/58/content/static_ram.html  https://moodle.insa-toulouse.fr/pluginfile.php/12869/mod_resource/content/0/content/index.html

Comment: @Antonio51 something like this yes